# Creating container relationship in declarative SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My Python / SQLAlchemy application manages a set of nodes, all derived from a base class *Node*.  I'm using SQLAlchemy's polymorphism features to manage
the nodes in a SQLite3 table. Here's the definition of the base *Node* class:

```
class Node(db.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    node_type = Column(String(40))
    title = Column(UnicodeText)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': node_type}
```

and, as an example, one of the derived classes, *NoteNode*:

```
class NoteNode(Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'note'}
    __tablename__ = 'nodes_note'
    id = Column(None,ForeignKey('nodes.id'),primary_key=True)
    content_type = Column(String)
    content = Column(UnicodeText)
```

Now I need a new kind of node, *ListNode*, that is an ordered container of zero or more *Node*s.  When I load a *ListNode*, I want it to have its ID and title
(from the base *Node* class) along with a collection of its contained (child) nodes. A *Node* may appear in more than one *ListNode*, so it's not a proper hierarchy. I would create them along these lines:

```
note1 = NoteNode(title=u"Note 1", content_type="text/text", content=u"I am note #1")
session.add(note1)

note2 = NoteNode(title=u"Note 2", content_type="text/text", content=u"I am note #2")
session.add(note2)

list1 = ListNode(title=u"My List")
list1.items = [note1,note2]
session.add(list1)
```

The list of children should only
consist of *Node* objects -- that is, all I need is their base class stuff. They shouldn't be fully realized into the specialized classes
(so I don't get the whole graph at once, among other reasons).

I started along the following lines, cobbling together bits and pieces I found in various places without a complete understanding of
what was going on, so this may not make much sense:

```
class ListNode(Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'list', 'inherit_condition':id==Node.id}
    __tablename__ = 'nodes_list_contents'
    id = Column(None, ForeignKey('nodes.id'), primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(None, ForeignKey('nodes.id'), primary_key=True)
    items = relation(Node, primaryjoin="Node.id==ListNode.item_id")
```

This approach fails in several ways: it doesn't appear to allow an empty *ListNode*, and setting the items attribute to a list results
in SQLAlchemy complaining that 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'.  Not surprisingly, hours of random mutations on this theme haven't given any
good results,

I have limited experience in SQLAlchemy but really want to get this working soon. I'd very much appreciate any advice or direction you can 
offer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an additional table for many-to-many relation:

```
nodes_list_nodes = Table(
    'nodes_list_nodes', metadata,
    Column('parent_id', None, ForeignKey('nodes_list.id'), nullable=False),
    Column('child_id', None, ForeignKey(Node.id), nullable=False),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('parent_id', 'child_id'),
)

class ListNode(Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'list'}
    __tablename__ = 'nodes_list'
    id = Column(None, ForeignKey('nodes.id'), primary_key=True)
    items = relation(Node, secondary=nodes_list_nodes)
```

**Update**: below is an example for ordered list using `association_proxy`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import InstrumentedList
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


class ListNodeAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes_list_nodes'
    parent_id = Column(None, ForeignKey('nodes_list.id'), primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(None, ForeignKey(Node.id), primary_key=True)
    order = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    child = relation(Node)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('parent_id', 'child_id'),
        {},
    )


class OrderedList(InstrumentedList):

    def append(self, item):
        if self:
            item.order = self[-1].order+1
        else:
            item.order = 1
        InstrumentedList.append(self, item)


class ListNode(Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'list'}
    __tablename__ = 'nodes_list'
    id = Column(None, ForeignKey('nodes.id'), primary_key=True)
    _items = relation(ListNodeAssociation,
                      order_by=ListNodeAssociation.order,
                      collection_class=OrderedList,
                      cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    items = association_proxy(
                '_items', 'child',
                creator=lambda item: ListNodeAssociation(child=item))
```

Comment: And this will result in "items" being a list of actual Item objects, correctly?  The binary relation winds up being completely transparent so that he doesn't need an associationproxy to skip past it to the actual objects, right?

Comment: Right, this case is easy. associationproxy is needed when you use intermediate model, i.e. to make list ordered (addition order field in connecting table).

Comment: Thanks so much, Denis - this has really broken the ice. If I may pursue it a bit further, I've rewritten the relation table in declarative style:

    class ListNodeAssociation(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'nodes_list_nodes'
        parent_id = Column(None, ForeignKey('nodes_list.id'),primary_key=True)
        child_id = Column(None, ForeignKey(Node.id),primary_key=True)

I still need the relationship to be in order, ideally via the SQLAlchemy 'orderinglist' mechanism, but I'm unclear how it applies in this situation... is it applicable, and if so, how?

Comment: You can update your original question properly marking new code as update. Or post another question (referring this one) with better title so that others can easily find it.

Comment: I've added an example for ordered list.

Comment: Thanks, Denis - works beautifully. And thanks for the tip on updating the question!